# I can't install requirements.txt of ibm qx quantum learning project

Tags: python, installation

this is error messeage of cmd:

```
(MQC) D:\Q_study\quantum-ibmqx>python chapter01/test_installation.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "chapter01/test_installation.py", line 6, in <module>
    import matplotlib
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'matplotlib'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "chapter01/test_installation.py", line 8, in <module>
    raise Exception("make sure to pip install -r requirements.txt")
Exception: make sure to pip install -r requirements.txt

(MQC) D:\Q_study\quantum-ibmqx>pip install -r requirements.txt
Requirement already satisfied: numpy==1.16.0 in d:\q_study\quantum-ibmqx\mqc\lib\site-packages (from -r requirements.txt (line 1)) (1.16.0)
Collecting matplotlib==3.0.3 (from -r requirements.txt (line 2))
  Using cached matplotlib-3.0.3.tar.gz (36.6 MB)
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × Getting requirements to build wheel did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [47 lines of output]
      ============================================================================
      Edit setup.cfg to change the build options

      BUILDING MATPLOTLIB
                  matplotlib: yes [3.0.3]
                      python: yes [3.8.10 (tags/v3.8.10:3d8993a, May  3 2021,
                              11:48:03) [MSC v.1928 64 bit (AMD64)]]
                    platform: yes [win32]

      REQUIRED DEPENDENCIES AND EXTENSIONS
                       numpy: yes [not found. pip may install it below.]
            install_requires: yes [handled by setuptools]
                      libagg: yes [pkg-config information for 'libagg' could not
                              be found. Using local copy.]
                    freetype: no  [The C/C++ header for freetype
                              (freetype2\ft2build.h) could not be found.  You may
                              need to install the development package.]
                         png: no  [The C/C++ header for png (png.h) could not be
                              found.  You may need to install the development
                              package.]
                       qhull: yes [pkg-config information for 'libqhull' could not
                              be found. Using local copy.]

      OPTIONAL SUBPACKAGES
                 sample_data: yes [installing]
                    toolkits: yes [installing]
                       tests: no  [skipping due to configuration]
              toolkits_tests: no  [skipping due to configuration]

      OPTIONAL BACKEND EXTENSIONS
                         agg: yes [installing]
                       tkagg: yes [installing; run-time loading from Python Tcl /
                              Tk]
                      macosx: no  [Mac OS-X only]
                   windowing: yes [installing]

      OPTIONAL PACKAGE DATA
                        dlls: no  [skipping due to configuration]

      ============================================================================
                              * The following required packages can not be built:
                              * freetype, png
                              * Please check http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packa
                              * ges/freetype.htm for instructions to install
                              * freetype
                              * Please check http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packa
                              * ges/libpng.htm for instructions to install png
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: subprocess-exited-with-error

× Getting requirements to build wheel did not run successfully.
│ exit code: 1
╰─> See above for output.

note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
```

I tried this suggestion of claude 3: The error message you are seeing indicates that numpy was successfully installed, but the installation of matplotlib is still failing due to missing dependencies. Specifically, matplotlib requires the freetype and libpng libraries to be installed on your system in order to render text and handle PNG images.

To resolve this issue, you need to install the development packages for freetype and libpng on your Windows system. The error message provides links to the respective packages on the GNUWin32 website:

For freetype, follow the instructions at http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/freetype.htm to download and install the package.
For libpng, follow the instructions at http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/libpng.htm to download and install the package.
After installing these development packages, try running pip install -r requirements.txt again. It should now be able to find the required headers and successfully install matplotlib.

If you still encounter issues after installing the development packages, you may need to ensure that the installation paths for these packages are included in your system's PATH environment variable.

Also, it's generally recommended to create a new virtual environment for each project to avoid conflicts between package versions and dependencies. If you haven't already, you might want to create a new virtual environment and install the required packages in that environment.

but I still got error. how can I fix this error?